# Weka LIbSVm & Time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, weka, regression, libsvm

I'm tryng to use LIBSVM regression for a forecast of 6 months in following data: 
I would use LIBSVM with RBF kernel and SVMTType-SVR with default data (I'm not expert to modify that)

Due the few data I evaluate on training data, but I receive a forecast of 0.5804 for each 6 months so it seems that something is wrong? I tried to also use grid search in weka looking for optimize the paramenters but the result is a constant forecast.

Does anyone have some suggestion to improve me?

Thanks

```
@relation Regression_test 

@attribute Period date yyyy-MM-dd 
@attribute Percentage numeric 

@data 
2011-08-01,0 
2011-09-01,0 
2011-10-01,0.259403 
2011-11-01,0.308642 
2011-12-01,0.613497 
2012-01-01,2.037662 
2012-02-01,1.134486 
2012-03-01,0.898727 
2012-04-01,0.465357 
2012-05-01,0.241168 
2012-06-01,0.354359 
2012-07-01,0.468987 
2012-08-01,0.320699 
2012-09-01,0.584155 
2012-10-01,0.786552 
2012-11-01,0.385395 
2012-12-01,0.302407 
2013-01-01,0.490101 
2013-02-01,0.446799 
2013-03-01,0.328194 
2013-04-01,0.431381 
2013-05-01,0.445664 
2013-06-01,0.557984 
2013-07-01,0.735813 
2013-08-01,0.82297 
2013-09-01,0.838937 
2013-10-01,1.06926 
2013-11-01,0.773331 
2013-12-01,0.408285 
2014-01-01,0.271486 
2014-02-01,0.394293 
2014-03-01,0.394572 
2014-04-01,0.563725 
2014-05-01,0.878016 
2014-06-01,0.766179
```